# Externalize strings and use a formatter to substitute variables into string

Tags: string, typescript, string-formatting, external

I'd like to externalize some strings but still use some form of string substitution.

In some of my `node` based projects I've used:

```
var format = require('string-format');

format(Constants.COUNTRY_WEATHER_ENDPOINT, {
  country: country
})
```

However In `Typescript`, I've been trying something like this ..

Error:

```
Cannot find name 'country'.at line 18 col 66 in repo/src/app/constants.ts
```

`Constants.ts`

```
export class Constants {
  public static COUNTRY_WEATHER_ENDPOINT = `/api/country/${country}/weather`;
}
```

`TestService.ts`

```
import { Constants } from './constants';

export class TestService {
  constructor(private $http) { }

  public getWeather(country) {
    let url = Constants.COUNTRY_WEATHER_ENDPOINT;
    return this.$http.get(
      url,
      .then(response => response);
  }
}

TestService.$inject = ['$http'];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use arrow functions:

```
export const Constants: { readonly [name: string]: (key: string) => string } = {
  countryWeatherEndpoint: country => `/api/country/${country}/weather`
}
```

Then do:

```
import { Constants } from "./constants";
// ...
const url = Constants.countryWeatherEndpoint(country);
// use your url
```

Comment: any idea how to get around `Parameter 'country' implicitly has an 'any' type.` without having to declare all vars at top of file

Comment: I changed the example: now it works with `noImplicitAny`.

Comment: You may take `{ readonly [name: string]: (key: string) => string }` and define it somewhere else as a type: e.g. `type ConstantsType = { readonly [name: string]: (key: string) => string }`. For instance in a file you can import wherever you need it. Then you can write `const Constants: ConstantsType = { ... }`

Answer (score 0):

String interpolation in Typescript needs your variable `country` to exist when class is loaded. If you want to format later the constant string, you have to use normal quotes (single or double) and call `format` in your service.